# How to get selector inside @media?

Tags: java, css, css-parsing

I'm trying to parse css by using [CSSParser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cssparser/)
For example, I have css:

```
 final String css = "@media screen and (color) { h1 { color: red } }";
```

I want to get this part:

```
{ h1 { color: red } }
```

But when I'm doing it by using mediaList

```
    final CSSStyleSheet sheet = parse(css);
    final CSSRule cssRule = sheet.getCssRules().item(0);
    final MediaList mediaList = ((CSSMediaRuleImpl) cssRule).getMedia();
```

I get only

Output: screen and (color)

Maybe somebody faced with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs answer :

```
@Test
public void testCSSParser2() throws IOException {
    String css = "@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {body { background-color: lightblue } h1 { color: red } }";
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(css));
    CSSOMParser parser = new CSSOMParser(new SACParserCSS3());
    CSSStyleSheet sheet = parser.parseStyleSheet(source, null, null);
    CSSRuleList rules = sheet.getCssRules();
    for (int x = 0; x < rules.getLength(); x++) {
        final CSSMediaRule mediaRule = ((CSSMediaRule) rules.item(x));
        CSSRuleList mediaRules = mediaRule.getCssRules();
        for (int y = 0; y < mediaRules.getLength(); y++) {
            final CSSRule rule = mediaRules.item(y);
            System.out.println(rule.getCssText());

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretending to know what this is all about, but
a

```
({.*})
```

regexp might help.